# rev function of n-dimensional lists

Tags: list, f#, reverse

I'm trying to make a function that take some list of type 'a list, where 'a could be of type 'b list, and 'b could be of type 'c list and so forth. it should revert every list in the list so that if 'a is a list then 'a should also be reverted and so forth.

```
let RevAll xs =
   let rec rev acc = function
       | (_::_)::__ as M -> rev ((rev List.Empty List.head M)::acc) (List.tail M)
       | x::xs           -> rev (x::acc) xs
       | []              -> acc
   rev List.Empty xs
```

Vs' compiler can't determent the types so it don't work. My question is as follow. Is there a way to make a function in F# that take an n-dimensional list and revert every dimension in that list without specifying the dimension?

Comment: Do you know the sublist nesting depth, or are you trying to a function that takes a parameter of different types?

Comment: the later one. It's purely for theoretic reasons. If it makes it simpler then we could say that the innermost list are of type int list but i rather like it to be generic

Comment: if you mean that, if I know how many "list" there is behind 'a then know, the idea is to eliminate the need to knowing the depths

Comment: A function normally cannot take a parameter of a type that is unknown at compile time.

Comment: I know but, if we take the normal List.rev as an example it takes some list of type 'a list where 'a could be some list itself. the only difference between mine and the List.rev is the first case else it is identical (List.rev only reverts the outermost list). I can't see why It can't make the same assumption of type in the first case? Is it a safeguard implemented into the langeuge? I know that the first case make it possible to have an infinite loop if it would work.

Comment: `List.rev` behaves identically for all parameter types. This is called "parametric polymorphism"", or in more simple terms "genericity". The function is generic. But you want your function to have different behavior depending on whether the element of the list is itself a list or not.

Comment: yes I would. was that a rhetoric answer or? I

Comment: Just try to write down the type of this function. You'll see.